# how to display a map location from your website using google maps

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe, onload

How do I display map locations on load from my database using google maps?

Let's say I have 3 addresses from my database:

```
1685 Centennial Way Corona California Riverside County 92882
25492 Centennial Way Corona California Riverside County 92882
1596 Centennial Way Corona California Riverside County 92882
```

They all have different pages, but I want them to **load the location in an iframe of google maps** when the user clicks the page. Is there any code that can help me to achieve that without manually embedding the iframe code from google maps website?

```
  <iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=1685+Centennial+Way+Corona+California+Riverside+County+92882&amp;aq=&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=42.089199,86.044922&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=1685+Centennial+Way,+Corona,+Riverside,+California+92882&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=33.858119,-117.598538&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=1685+Centennial+Way+Corona+California+Riverside+County+92882&amp;aq=&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=42.089199,86.044922&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=1685+Centennial+Way,+Corona,+Riverside,+California+92882&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=33.858119,-117.598538" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

Generate all these values from my website to eliminate the need to manually get the code from google maps.

Comment: What kind of database is this? What kind of web server? Are you wanting simply the HTML/JS solution, or the full PHP/SQL (or other) solution?

Comment: the full PHP/SQL , Hosted webserver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Google Maps, there is a Link button (looks like a chain) which gives you the HTML for an iframe with your searched location.

For example, for your first example, it is as follows (line breaks inserted for readability):

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0"
scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"
src="https://maps.google.com/maps?
f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;
q=1685+Centennial+Way+Corona+California+Riverside+County+92882&amp;
aq=&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=53.87374,114.082031&amp;
ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=1685+Centennial+Way,+Corona,+Riverside,+California+92882&amp;
t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=33.858119,-117.598538&amp;output=embed">
</iframe>
```

The GPS data is unnecessary here, so you can make it:

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0"
scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"
src="https://maps.google.com/maps?
f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;
q=1685+Centennial+Way+Corona+California+Riverside+County+92882&amp;
ie=UTF8&amp;hnear=1685+Centennial+Way,+Corona,+Riverside,+California+92882&amp;
t=m&amp;output=embed">
</iframe>
```

The link version, if necessary, is the same, except without escaped &s (&):

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=1685+Centennial+Way+Corona+California+Riverside+County+92882&aq=&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=1685+Centennial+Way,+Corona,+Riverside,+California+92882
```

You can then replace the address component with the relevant one (and properly URL-encode it) with your choice of scripting language.